# VS2010 doesn't show project's CodeAnalysis page

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

When I try to open a project's CodeAnalysis page I get the error

"An error occurred trying to load the page.
Only TrueType fonts are supported. This is not a TrueType font."

I also get a very simmilar ExceptionBox when I want to open the solution's propertywindow:

"Only TrueType fonts are supported. This is not a TrueType font."

Has anyone experiences with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue.

As described [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/336125/wpf-designer-error-only-truetype-fonts-are-supported-this-is-not-a-truetype-font) I changed the fontsettings of icons from MS Sans Serif to Tahoma and everything works fine now.